# Panel isn't filling the space between the flow layout panel

Tags: c#, winforms, flowlayoutpanel

I have this form, where the light blue is a flow layout panel and the white is a panel inside it.

[image: This is the image of the VS windows forms].

It looks like this when running:

[image: This is the end result]

If you look carefully, you can see a small border around the edge of the white section.

Why doesn't the panel fill the space inside the flow layout panel? I haven't done any coding; I just saw a guy placed the panel over and it automatically filled the space.

Comment: Set the child Panel's `Margin.All` to `0`

Comment: Hi Martin glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. 
It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the margin was bugging it. I fixed it by setting the margin to 0, it was 3 by default. Thanks to Jimi.

Answer (score -1):

You should set Panel.Dock to Fill, then it adapts it's size automatically to the flow layout panel. Default for Dock is usaually None, in this case it always keeps the same size.

Comment: I have done that but without success. The result is the same.